# How to close modal after clicking on link inside modal in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, angular7

i am giving link inside modal which will go on another page on clicking. when link opens another page the modal doesnot get close so i need help in closing modal.

×
            

        
        
          Important Note

We strongly recommend you for Individual reservation.

Continue as Couple...

Answer (score 1):

let's say in your modal you have a snippet of code as below

**`in component.html`**

```
<a (click)="goToNextPage()" >click here</a>
```

and in the `component.ts`file add the following code

in **`component.ts`**

```
constructor(
    private router:Router,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent> //replace your modal component here,
  ) { }

goToNextPage(){
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigate(['/nextPageURL']);
}
```

for better understanding check the [**`official doc`**](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)